# Pull request to forked repo in GitHub and ignore deletion of .idea files

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I am trying to understand some concepts of GIT and I cannot figure out how exactly works.
My teacher has a Java project and I:

- forked to my repository
- cloned the repo from my GIT to local
- I added .yml files and .idea folder to .gitignore
- `git rm --cached -r .yml`... and pushed to my repo (they disappeared from the repository, but I thought that it will be only removed from the staging area on my local machine)
- Then I try to contribute with "Create Pull Request", and there appear the changes I had made, but also showing that .idea folder and its inner files are deleted ("Load Diff/This file was deleted").

**So, I suppose that in my commitment to the forked repo there will be a request to delete the .idea folder in the original/forked repo.
In few words, how can I contribute to the project without requesting my teacher delete his .idea, *yml files...**

P.S. I'm sorry for the probably naive question, but I couldn't find any solution, and maybe the reason is that I generally don't understand how GIT works. Thanks for your help.

Here are the Comparing changes:
[image]

Comment: What you mean by 'they disappeared from them, which I don't understand why too?'

Comment: "I generally don't understand how GIT works" The first step would probably be to understand it. Let me help you: https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/

Comment: "but also showing that .idea folder and its inner files are deleted" That is not what your screen shot shows, so it is unclear what the question is about. Your screen shows something quite different, namely that you added some lines about `.idea` files in the `.gitignore` file, as you mentioned earlier ("I added .yml files and .idea folder to .gitignore").

Comment: @ZahidKhan I changed it. I mean that I can't understand why rm --cached removes the files from the origin repository

Comment: @matt couldn't it be so? That he has added `.idea` in the `.gitignore` but git is not ignoring the folder `.idea`? As I faced such issues multiple times, so I have had to update index by  `git rm --cached .` followed by `git reset`.

Comment: @ZahidKhan Of course it could be so, I'm just saying that screen shot didn't include the deletion. I believe in the deletion. But if that's what the screen shot is supposed to be about, it's a bad screen shot.

Comment: @matt I will check out the link, thank you. Sorry, if wasn't clear, but my main asking is that I marked the .idea folder with rm --cached, but when I make the Pull Request to the forked repository they are still inside the Pull Request, so if me teacher merge the request, they will be deleted from his repo?

Comment: @AlexandarDimov and I've tried to answer that question.

Answer (score 1):

Git deals in *commits*. Your life with Git is about creating and possibly sharing commits. A commit describes the *entire* state of your project.

So if there is a file *myfile* in commit A and you then delete that file and make a commit B that encompasses that deletion (i.e. commit B lacks the file *myfile*), that is the history: there was a file *myfile* and now there isn't. And that is what you did when you said `git rm --cached` and then `git commit`.

So when you make a pull request, that is a *merge*. A merge enacts the contributions of two or more branches — everything their commits did independently. On your branch, part of your contribution was the deletion of *myfile*. So merging your branch into a branch that still has *myfile* can mean that *myfile* gets deleted.

Comment: I suggest that you read first my article on what Git is https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/ and then my article on what a merge is https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/

Comment: Thank you, @matt. I should definitely get more familiar with Git, and I will check out the links.